# How do I build a C extension as a submodule to a C extension main module with distutils?

Tags: python-3.x, distutils, python-c-api, distutils2

I have two files, `module.c` and `submodule.c`.

I have the following code in setup.py:

```
from distutils.core import setup, Extension

module = Extension('module', sources = ['module.c'])

submodule = Extension('submodule', sources = ['submodule.c'])

setup (name = 'module',
       version = '0.1',
       description = 'a module that does things',
       ext_modules = [module, submodule])
```

I build it as below:

```
$ DISTUTILS_DEBUG=1 python3 setup.py build
```

In the python shell, when I do the following:

```
>>> import module # works
>>> from module import submodule # this should work
...
ImportError: cannot import name 'submodule' from 'module' (/home/username/Projects/module/build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/module.cpython-38-x86_64-linux-gnu.so)
>>> import module.submodule # is this supposed to work?
...
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'module.submodule'; 'module' is not a package
>>> import submodule # This should not work
...
ImportError: dynamic module does not define module export function (PyInit_submodule)
```

Do note that in the last case (`import submodule`), my `PyInit` function was named `PyInit_module_submodule()`, which threw the `ImportError`. If I change it to `PyInit_submodule()`, then `import submodule` works.

I probably have a fundamental misunderstanding of how modules work in Python, so all help is appreciated.

Comment: `submodule = Extension('module.submodule', sources = ['submodule.c'])` See https://stackoverflow.com/a/58131417/7976758

Comment: That did not work. Now only ```import submodule``` works, while ```from module import submodule``` still does not work, and neither does ```import module.submodule```.

Comment: Do you want to create a package? How would you do what you want to do with normal py-files?

Comment: To be honest, I don't know. I haven't made packages with normal python files. Just simple single-file modules that were straightforward to import.