# Python extension module in its own directory

Tags: python, pip, distutils

I want my python extension module (`pymyext1.pyd`) to be under `site-packages/pymyext1/` directory. In `site-packages/pymyext1/` there should be two files: `__init__.py` and `pymyext1.pyd`.
`__init__.py` contains a simple import of `pymyext1.pyd`.

How my setup function in my `setup.py` should look like? Currently, I have this:

```py
setup(
    name="pymyext1",
    version="0.1",
    ext_modules=[Extension("pymyext1", ["main.c"])],
    include_package_data=True,
    package_dir={"pymyext1": "pymyext1"},
    packages=["pymyext1"],
    package_data={"pymyext1": ["*.pyd"]},
)
```

My directories organized as follows:

```
setup.py
pymyext1/
    __init__.py
main.c
```

But after `pip install .` I find `pymyext1.pyd` in `site-packages` directory, but not in `site-packages/pymyext1/` as I want.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/58131417/7976758 and https://stackoverflow.com/a/54223150/7976758. You need to make it `Extension("pymyext1.pymyext1", ["main.c"])`

Comment: Also `package_dir` is not needed with your directory structure because your package is right under the root. Remove it. `package_dir` is for src/lib-style directory structure.