# Edit location of compiled files with setuptools

Tags: python, pip, cython, setuptools, cythonize

I am using setuptools to compile a pyx file using Cython using the following code in my setup.py

```
from Cython.Distutils import build_ext

extensions=[Extension("filtering.filter", "filtering/filter.pyx")

setup(
   name="..",
   ........
   ext_modules=extensions,
   cmdclass={"build_ext", build_ext}
   include_dirs=[".", numpy.get_include()]
)
```

I want to use `pip install .` to install this rather than `python setup.py ...`
When running `pip install .` it compiles the file correctly, but stores it in the wrong place, it stores it in `filtering/` rather than `my_project/filtering/`

I have tried using a `setup.cfg` with `inplace=1` and also tried `build_lib=.` but this does not put it in the correct place either
Any help appreciated

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58131417/7976758 In your case it should be `extensions=[Extension("my_project.filtering.filter", "filtering/filter.pyx")`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm writing a package in which all the code goes inside the `src` directory, and this approach works fine for me.

**Package structure**

```
src
 |-- foo
 |   |-- foo.pyx
 |
 |-- setup.py
 |-- setup.cfg
 |-- (.toml, LICENSE ... )
```

**setup.cfg**

```
[metadata]
.
.
.
[options]
packages = find:
package_dir = src
.
.
.
[options.packages.find]
where = src
```

**setup.py**

```
from setuptools import setup
from setuptools.extension import Extension
from Cython.Build import cythonize

ext_modules = [
    Extension(
        name = "foo.foo.pyx",
        sources = ["src/foo/foo.pyx"]
    )
]

if __name__ == "__main__":

    setup(
        ext_modules=cythonize(ext_modules)
    )
```

I'm not sure if the last part of the `.cfg` file (where ...) is strictly necessary.